# time config parameter in apache flume to write the data in HDFS

Tags: flume, flume-ng

Is there any config parameter that we can specify in the flume config file to write the data from kafka queue to HDFS at specific interval.

I have seen batchsize, but we dont want to use it because it keeps waiting to fill up the buffer based on the batchsize and then write data in HDFS.

Comment: what about hdfs.rollInterval ?

Comment: Will try this and let you know. Thank you!!

Comment: Actually it is batchDurationMillis